# What's meaning of "EXPORT_SYMBOL" in Linux kernel code?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

from [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/sound/core/init.c?v=2.6.35;a=arm#L48)

```
 48 struct snd_card *snd_cards[SNDRV_CARDS];
 49 EXPORT_SYMBOL(snd_cards);
```

I am not getting whats the meaning of it and why that is used. I tried to search about it but not understanding the meaning of that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670589/use-of-export-symbol might be of use

Comment: excellent information on this can be found [hear](http://tuxthink.blogspot.in/2011/07/exporting-symbols-from-module.html)

Comment: Minimal runnable example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44614246/895245

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It makes a symbol accessible to dynamically loaded modules (provided that said modules add an `extern` declaration).

Not long ago, [someone asked how to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9820518/714501).

Comment: @cirosantilli It is defined in `include/linux/export.h`. Look for `ksymtab` and `kstrtab`.

Comment: Anyone know under what version of the kernel /include/linux/export.h was added?(Or an easy way to check without going through every single kernel source tree) I'm not seeing it in 2.6.39.4.

Comment: When we are using kernel symbols like jiffies, why is it not required to do extern that time?

Answer (score 12):

Here is a good explanation.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-extern-and-EXPORT_SYMBOL-in-Linux-kernel-codes

> Extern is a C storage class keyword. In the kernel, as in any other C
>   code, it tells the compiler that the definition of the variable or
>   function it qualifies is implemented in another “file”, or rather,
>   more accurately Translation unit (programming) - Wikipedia. The
>   translation unit that does define it should not use the static
>   qualifier. Therefore, the symbol table has an entry corresponding to
>   it. At link time, the symbol is resolved as normal. There is nothing
>   kernel specific about “extern”.
>
> EXPORT_SYMBOL() is a macro the Linux kernel headers define. It has not
>   much in common with extern. It tells the kbuild mechanism that the
>   symbol referred to should be part of the global list of kernel
>   symbols. That, in turn allows kernel modules to access them. Code that
>   is built into the kernel itself (as opposed to a module) can, of
>   course, access any non-static symbol via an extern declaration, in
>   accordance with regular C. The EXPORT_SYMBOL() mechanism allows us to
>   export a symbol for use by loadable modules as well. An interesting
>   thing is that a symbol thus exported by one module becomes accessible
>   to another module that may depend on it!
>
> To summarise, extern is not kernel specific. It is used to qualify a
>   declaration to a non-static symbol from another translation unit.
>   EXPORT_SYMBOL() is specific to the Linux kernel. It is used in the
>   translation unit of the definition to make the symbol available to
>   loadable modules.

So EXPORT_SYMBOL is just a mechanism like extern, but it's for reference between loadable modules not file.

To move forwards, we can guess it's achived by the extern  because extern is form C which is the foundation.

Here is a clue.

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.6.7/source/include/linux/export.h#L56

```
#define EXPORT_SYMBOL(sym)                  \
    __EXPORT_SYMBOL(sym, "")

/* For every exported symbol, place a struct in the __ksymtab section */
#define __EXPORT_SYMBOL(sym, sec)               \
    extern typeof(sym) sym;                 \
    __CRC_SYMBOL(sym, sec)                  \
    static const char __kstrtab_##sym[] __attribute__((section("__ksymtab_strings"), aligned(1)))  = VMLINUX_SYMBOL_STR(sym);               \
    extern const struct kernel_symbol __ksymtab_##sym;  \
    __visible const struct kernel_symbol __ksymtab_##sym    __used __attribute__((section("___ksymtab" sec "+" #sym), unused)) = { (unsigned long)&sym, __kstrtab_##sym }
```

First declare a  extern sym.

Then a string __kstrtab_##sym = = VMLINUX_SYMBOL_STR(sym).

Last a extern struct  kernel_symbol __ksymtab_##sym = { (unsigned long)**&sym**, **__kstrtab_##sym** }.    **&sym** record the real address of the sym such as a function or variable,  _***kstrtab*##sym** record the name string.

Answer (score 6):

Not an answer per se but a demonstration, as promised from my comment, that exported symbols *are not* required to be non-static.  The below 2 modules demonstrate this:

```
/* mod1.c */
#include <linux/module.h>

static int mod1_exp_func(int i)
{
    pr_info("%s:%d the value passed in is %d\n",
            __func__, __LINE__, i);

    return i;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(mod1_exp_func); /* export static symbol */

static int __init mod1_init(void)
{
    pr_info("Initializing simple mod\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit mod1_exit(void)
{
    pr_info("This module is exiting\n");
}

module_init(mod1_init);
module_exit(mod1_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL v2");
```

And the second module

```
/* mod2.c */
#include <linux/module.h>

extern int mod1_exp_func(int);

static int __init mod2_init(void)
{
    pr_info("Initializing mod2\n");
    pr_info("Calling exported function in mod1\n");
    mod1_exp_func(3);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit mod2_exit(void)
{
    pr_info("mod2 exiting\n");
}

module_init(mod2_init);
module_exit(mod2_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL v2");
```

These were tested on CentOS 6 & CentOS 7: kernels 2.6.32 and 3.10 (respectively).  Loading mod1.ko and then mod2.ko will result in the value passed to mod1_exp_func() being printed to the kernel log buffers.

Comment: Does it work if the functions are non static? Because I tried making the functions non static and while one of the files was present in a subdirectory, making that module was throwing a warning saying that the exported functions are undefined in the module present in the subdirectory. And when i made the definitions static, it worked.