# Linux kernel exported symbols

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I want to check the list of symbol exported by the Linux kernel. 
So I fire the command,

```
# cat /proc/kallsyms
0000000000000000 D per_cpu__irq_stack_union
0000000000000000 D __per_cpu_start
0000000000004000 D per_cpu__gdt_page
0000000000005000 d per_cpu__exception_stacks
000000000000b000 d per_cpu__idt_desc
000000000000b010 d per_cpu__xen_cr0_value
000000000000b018 D per_cpu__xen_vcpu
000000000000b020 D per_cpu__xen_vcpu_info
000000000000b060 d per_cpu__mc_buffer
000000000000c570 D per_cpu__xen_mc_irq_flags
```

This is the output I got.
My question is that, what is the meaning of each field in this output?
The first field looks like the address, I didn't get any reference for second field.
Can anybody explain to me the meaning of the values, D,d,t,T,s in second field?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The characters in the second column have the same meaning they do in the output from `nm`:

> `D`
> `d` The symbol is in the initialized data section.
>
> `S`
> `s` The symbol is in an uninitialized data section for small objects.
>
> `T`
> `t` The symbol is in the text (code) section.

Uppercase symbols are global/exported; lowercase are local unexported symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding symbols exported by the Linux kernel

The `/proc/kallsyms` and `System.map` files contain the list of symbols that are present in the Linux kernel. However, only symbols that are marked in kernel with `EXPORT_SYMBOL` and some other related macros are available to external kernel modules. Symbols from `/proc/kallsyms` that are marked with `T` - global/exported - are available to kernel code, but not all of them are available to external kernel modules.

There is `Module.symvers` file that lists symbols that are available to external kernel modules. As Linux kernel documentation - [link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt) - says: "During a kernel build, a file named `Module.symvers` will be generated. `Module.symvers` contains all exported symbols from the kernel and compiled modules".

References:

- [Linux kernel documentation describing, among other things, Module.symvers file](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt)
- ["What's meaning of "EXPORT_SYMBOL" in Linux kernel code?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836467/whats-meaning-of-export-symbol-in-linux-kernel-code)
- [System.map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System.map)