# Providing permissions for a root user in a kernel module

Tags: c, linux, permissions, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

`Linux Kernel 5.0.0-37`

I'm writing a function to manage permissions to be provided as a function pointer to the [`struct inode_operations`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/vfs.html#id1). Here is a simplified stub implementation:

```
#include <linux/cred.h>

int pfsw_permission(struct inode *ino, int op){
    if(uid_eq(INIT_USER->uid, get_current_user()->uid)){
        printk(KERN_INFO "Current user is root\n");
    } else {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Current user is not root\n");
    }
    if(op & (MAY_READ | MAY_WRITE)){
        return 0;
    }

    return -EACCES;
}
```

when compiling a kernel module containing this function and trying to load it `dmesg` shows the following error:

```
Unknown symbol root_user (err -2)
```

This I think is due to `INIT_USER` macro coming from [include/linux/sched/user.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/sched/user.h#L49) which is defined as

```
extern struct user_struct root_user;
#define INIT_USER (&root_user)
```

**QUESTION:** Why is the symbol `root_user` declared, but not defined? How to use `INIT_USER` correctly?

Comment: This is certainly not the right way to accomplish whatever your goal is.  Do some thinking about what existing piece of standard functionality would have a similar need, and then look up how that was implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`root_user` does not [seem](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/root_user) to be exported using [`EXPORT_SYMBOL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57881867/1116364) by the linux kernel; therefore you cannot use it from a module.

Looking at [its definition](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/46cf053efec6a3a5f343fead837777efe8252a46/kernel/user.c#L104) we can see that the `uid` value is set to `GLOBAL_ROOT_UID`.  This is a macro defined in `include/linux/uidgid.h` and is basically just a type cast of 0 to `kuid_t` so you can use just that macro if all you need is the UID.

So ...

> Why is the symbol `root_user` declared, but not defined?

The symbol is defined. It's not exported though so you cannot use it from a module.

> How to use `INIT_USER` correctly?

"Not". You cannot use it.